# C++ popen not getting all of stdout

Tags: c++, stdout, iostream, popen, apt-get

Basically I want to read all data from stdout when running a program with popen. However, the program I run will not return the last output line into my buffer and I do not understand why (my understanding: I would get any output sent to stdout {unbuffered?} from popen).

```
// $Id: popen.cpp 126 2011-04-25 18:48:02Z wus $

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

/**
 * run debians apt-get and check output
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) { 

    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[9];
    // select a package which is not installed and has uninstalled dependencies, 
    // apt-get will ask if it should installed «Y» or nor «n».
    char command[255] = "apt-get install python-wxtools";
    cout << command << endl;

    // Execute command, open /dev/stdout for reading
    fp = popen(command, "r");

    // read output character by character
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 1, fp) != EOF) {
        cout << buffer;
    }

    // close
    pclose(fp);
}
```

native output looks like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-wxtools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion
Suggested packages:
  wx2.8-doc wx2.8-examples ruby wish tk8.5 tcsh csh octave3.0 mksh pdksh
  python-xml editra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools python-wxversion
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,942kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.0MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

NOTE: no newline at the end of the last line.

when I use my own program, the last line is missing (output)

```
$ sudo ./test/popen 
g++ -Wall -o test/popen test/popen.cpp
test/popen.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**, char**)’:
test/popen.cpp:22: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
apt-get install python-wxtools
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxversion
Suggested packages:
  wx2.8-doc wx2.8-examples ruby wish tk8.5 tcsh csh octave3.0 mksh pdksh
  python-xml editra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools python-wxversion
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,942kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.0MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

NOTE: newline at the end of output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that you aren't reading the last line, the problem is that you aren't displaying it due to cout being line buffered.

```
cout << buffer << flush;
```

should work.

Comment: This is interesting. IF I use it my console seems to hang when the program ends.

Comment: Strange.  Doesn't here.  Which terminal emulator are you using?

Answer (score 4):

fread does not return EOF when it reaches end of file.  Rather, it returns 0.  But I suspect the problem is that apt-get is detecting that its input is not a tty and is thus not printing the prompt at all.

Comment: And there is no guarantee that what it read is null-terminated, so output via the `<<` operator is dubious at best.

Comment: which function should I use to be able to read up until the end of the input stream?

Comment: +1 for remarking the fread problem. For the source of display problem see my answer.

Comment: @Spliffster  If you just want to read one character at a time, use fgetc or getc.

Comment: @William Pursell: I have tried fgetc, same result, my man pages says: "Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data  in  advance  how  many  characters  gets() will read, and because ..." should I use it?

Comment: @Spliffster.  Do not use gets.  Never use gets.  Never.

Comment: Is apt-get writing to stderr?